# ¿Por qué "ni jota" equivale a "nada"?

Tags: etimología, historia, letras

[**Jota**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MXlpsMD) es

> 1. f. Letra j y sonido que representa.
>   2. f. En la baraja francesa o el dado de póquer, elemento marcado con una J y que a veces representa la figura de un paje.

En esa entrada también se recogen varias locuciones en las que pasa a tener un significado equivalente a *nada*:

> **ni jota**
>   1. loc. pronom. coloq. nada (‖ ninguna cantidad). U. con neg. *No sabe ni jota de eso.*
>
> **sin faltar jota, o una jota**
>   1. locs. advs. coloqs. desus. sin faltar una coma.
>
> **una jota**
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. Muy poco o nada. La celebración le importaba una jota. U. t. c. loc. pronom. *No entendía una jota de matemáticas.*

¿Cómo se ha pasado de las acepciones originales a los significados de *nada* en las locuciones?

Answer (score 9):

Interesante pregunta. Ante estos casos lo que suelo hacer es buscar en diccionarios antiguos a ver hasta dónde llegan estas definiciones, y resulta que en este caso tienen bastante tiempo. Encuentro la siguiente definición en el Terreros y Pando de 1787:

> JOTA. Cast. se toma tambien por la particula pequeña de alguna cosa, y es sacado de la expresion del Evanjelio. Fr. *Jota*. Lat. *I, apex. Al libro que habeis escrito, no le falta una jota, ó un apice.*

Más atrás, en 1706, el diccionario español-inglés de Stevens decía:

> Jota. A Jot, a Scrap, a Tittle.

Curioso que tanto *jot* como *scrap* se traduzcan como "pizca" (y "tittle" como "pequeña marca o punto en la escritura", palabra cognada de nuestra "tilde"), con lo que volvemos a la idea de "algo insignificante" o "nada", como decías en la pregunta. Y más curioso aún que ya tengamos una traducción de *jota* al francés como "jota" y al inglés como "jot". Aquí se empieza a ver una raíz común. Así que curioseando en diccionarios etimológicos del idioma inglés descubro lo siguiente:

> **[jot (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jot)**
>
> "the least part of anything," 1520s, from Latin *iota*, from Greek *iota* "the letter -i-," the smallest letter in the Greek alphabet, also "the least part of anything" (see **iota**). Usually (and originally) with **tittle**, from Matthew v.18.

Traduciendo, que todo viene de que la letra griega "iota", que da nombre a la nuestra, era la letra más pequeña del alfabeto griego. Y además tenemos aquí la referencia al Evangelio que ya nos advirtió el diccionario de Terreros y Pando. La referencia hace alusión a este versículo:

> *En verdad os digo que, hasta que pasen el cielo y la tierra, no pasará una iota ni un ápice de la ley antes de que se haya cumplido todo.*
>
> Mateo 5,18.

Y este es el origen de la expresión: hace alusión a la *iota* como la letra más pequeña del alfabeto (aunque no por ello menos importante que las demás). Aunque al parecer, no se refería al alfabeto griego, [sino al hebreo](https://lp.israelbiblicalstudies.com/lp_iibs_biblical_hebrew_know_the_word_of_jesus_v2-en.html?cid=52972&adgroupid=-1&utm_source=Email_Marketing&utm_medium=The_word_of_Jesus_04_18&utm_campaign=BIB_EN_EML_Word_of_Jesus_2018-04-21_52972&stid=5266860&hash=e50cf8489e78e75cafdf64fb29b6054a&_at=0.3.9666079,0.138169886.z3azwjaajdaudc8uu8&_atscid=3_2483_138169886_9666079_0_Tz3azwjaajdaudc8uu8):

> Jesus said that **“not one letter…will pass from the law until all is accomplished” (Matthew 5:18)**. The original Greek text of the Gospel of Matthew says **“not one iota”**. The Greek letter iota is derived from the Hebrew letter **yod**. Its name comes from the Hebrew word **yad (יד)** meaning “hand”, because it is shaped like a little finger. *Yod* is so small that ancient scribes sometimes left it out of words to save space.

Traducido: la letra hebrea *yod* era tan pequeña que los antiguos escribas solían omitirla para ahorrar espacio. Esta idea de "jota" como "algo pequeño, insignificante" ha perdurado hasta nuestros días.

Por último, os dejo con el caso más antiguo de la expresión que he encontrado en el CORDE (y es bastante antiguo):

> *Assí que todos los santos que son en el mundo non podrán amansar una jota de la yra de Dios, fasta que sea purificado e alynpiado el santuario [...].*
>
> San Vicente Ferrer, "Sermones", 1411-1412 (España).